# Using Google Mock for pointer to array allocated in call?

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing, googlemock

Given the following C/C++ code:

```
#define MAX_LEN 256
typedef struct {
  int id;
  char val[MAX_LEN];
} CfgInfoType;

CfgInfoType* pCfgInfo;

int getCfg(CfgInfoType** ppCfgInfo)
{
  int n = determineN();  /* An example, real code a little more complex */
  *ppCfgInfo = (CfgInfoType*) malloc(sizeof(CfgInfoType) * n);
  /* Code to fill in *pCfgInfo array here */
  return n;
}
```

I do not like this code, it allocates memory as a side effect that requires the caller to free.  However before I change the code I'd like to mock getCfg() so that I can build a set of characterization tests around the callers.  getCfg() is basically allocating and returning a pointer to a contiguous array.  But I have not been able to setup a Google Mock that will populate that array for getCfg() callers/clients.  In addition, the callers free the memory, so to test the callers, the mock actually has to allocate the memory or mock the memory as allocated so the free() calls do not cause a segmentation violation. Tried many things, among them:

```
CfgInfoType* pCfgInfo = (CfgInfoType*) malloc(sizeof(CfgInfoType) * 2);
pCfgInfo[0].id = 1;
strcpy(pCfgInfo[0].val, "value 1");
pCfgInfo[1].id = 2;
strcpy(pCfgInfo[1].val, "value 2");

EXPECT_CALL(mockObj, getCfg(NotNull())).WillOnce(DoAll(SetArrayArgument<0>(pCfgInfo, pCfgInfo+2), Return(2));
```

or:

```
EXPECT_CALL(mockObj, getCfg(NotNull())).WillOnce(DoAll(SetArgPointee<0>(pCfgInfo), Return(2));
```

Beginning to think this is not doable. Or should I say not "mockable"?

Thanks in advance for any help!
Chris

Comment: FYI: there is no language called C/C++. As C you should not cast the result of `malloc`, and as C++ `typedef struct`, use of `malloc`, et. al. are not idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks crashmstr for pointing out all the technical errors in my presentation.  My goal here was not to be technically correct or as exacting as you seem to require, but to just provide enough information to try to get the question answered. But thanks for you advice, even though it has nothing to do with addressing the question being asked.

Comment: My point being that you should only tag the relevant language, generally only the one being written/compiled (and know which language you are using).

Comment: The getCfg() call is being made in a C++ module.  But it is defined in a C module.  So the C module (much older code) is doing the malloc.  I didn't mean to name the language C/C++, I meant I am working in a mixed C/C++ environment.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly doable. What you need is a custom action:

```
ACTION_P(SetCfgInfoPtrToPtr, value)
{
    *reinterpret_cast<CfgInfoType**>(arg0) = value;
}
```

The action above does what you want but it is too restrictive because the type of pointer and argument index are fixed. I suggest usage of a generalized templatized action that allows you to set the type and argument index via template. This can be achieved via `ACTION_TEMPLATE`. The first template parameter (`Type`) is the type of pointer, the second (`uIndex`) is an integral value that represents index of the function parameter. Inside `ACTION_TEMPLATE`, you can access all arguments via `args`, which is a `std::tuple`. Therefore, we can apply `std::get` in combination with `uIndex` to get the correct function parameter (For example, `std::get<0>(args)` gives us `arg0`). We then cast this parameter to `Type**`, dereference it and assing the desired value to the pointee. Here is a complete definition:

```
ACTION_TEMPLATE(SetArgPtrToPtr, HAS_2_TEMPLATE_PARAMS(typename, Type, unsigned, uIndex), AND_1_VALUE_PARAMS(value))
{
    *reinterpret_cast<Type**>(std::get<uIndex>(args)) = value;
}
```

This action , as well as the value that will be assigned to the pointee.
In your case, this is how you should use it:

```
EXPECT_CALL(mockObj, getCfg(NotNull()))
    .WillOnce(
        DoAll(
            SetArgPtrToPtr<CfgInfoType, 0>(pCfgInfo),
            Return(2)
        )
    );
```

Comment: Marko Thanks for the response! It's going to take a while to digest as I haven't used ACTION_TEMPLATEs before.  Have to read the Google CookBook to further understand what you're doing here.

Comment: @Ratso You are welcome! I've updated my answer. It now contains a simple custom action, as well as clarification of the implementation of template action. Hope this helps! Consider marking the answer as accepted if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is nice API called [Typemock Isolator++](https://www.typemock.com/docs?book=Ipp) for unit-test frameworks. It has a simple solution for mocking methods with reference parameters. Take a look:

```
TEST_METHOD(RETAndSpecificReturnValue)
{
    //Arrange
    int n = 2;
    CfgInfoType* pCfgInfo = (CfgInfoType*)malloc(sizeof(CfgInfoType) * n);
    pCfgInfo[0].id = 1;
    strcpy(pCfgInfo[0].val, "value 1");
    pCfgInfo[1].id = 2;
    strcpy(pCfgInfo[1].val, "value 2");

    FAKE_GLOBAL(getCfg);
    WHEN_CALLED(getCfg(RET(&pCfgInfo))).Return(n);

    //Act
    CfgInfoType* cfgTest = NULL;
    int result = getCfg(&cfgTest);

    //Assert
    Assert::AreEqual(result, n);
    Assert::IsNotNull(cfgTest);
}
```

Hope it'll be useful for you!

Comment: Thanks Sam!  I'm in an organization with a lot of developers and a large code base, not sure if I have enough control of the code to add a new test framework.  Would have to work with the Configuration Management team to get it added.

Comment: The trick is that it isn't a new framework. It's an API, which just need to be downloaded, linked to your framework, a little setting up.. and enjoy!